# What is the derivative of $U^{\rm T}(t)V(t)U(t)$?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Is this correct ?

$$\frac{{\rm d}~[U^{\rm T}(t)V(t)U(t)]}{{\rm d}t}=U^{\rm T}(t)V(t){\rm d}(U(t))+U^{\rm T}(t)U(t){\rm d}(V(t))+V(t)U(t){\rm d}(U^{\rm T}(t))$$

Please note that $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Comment: The order of multiplication matters when you are doing matrix.

Comment: There is a $W(t)$ in the title, but no such thing in the question statement.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you, Actually I thought of denoting transposed matrix as W later changed my mind. Edited title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We obtain: $(U')^TVU+U^TV'U+U^TVU'$.